# Conditionally loading content for adaptive design server-side with WURFL

Tags: rwd, conditional-loading

Trying to figure out the best way to only serve content that is needed in a responsive design (as opposed to just hiding hundreds of elements in CSS).

I notice at `/lib/Zend/Http/UserAgent/Features/Adapter` there are some files for device detection like `WurflApi.php` - does Magento have the ability to just load content with an if statement via WURFL already? If not, can anyone advise of any tools that can cater for this?

I wrote more about our requirements for this [here](http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/topic/72894-conditional-responsive-design-vs-adaptive-design-for-magento/).

Link to [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) for more info.

Comment: Never heard of Wurfl and I think I opened most of the Magento files already :-) to answer the question whether this works already. Not that I know of

Comment: It's really frustrating me. It's packaged with the Zend library it seems but I can't find any documentation anywhere to see if Magento uses this / has the capability of serving content based on device detection using [WURFL's](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) database. :(

Comment: Magento brings many things with Zend but most of them are not used!

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying that. I think that answers my question really (considering the docs on this are non existent). Now to write something that allows WURFL to be used in Magento then! Cheers.

Comment: github and open source is your friend ;-)